# Finding the least possible number of containers for varied integer values

Tags: optimization, integer-programming

So I feel like I'm in elementary school again, but I have an optimization problem I've been banging my head against, I'll abstract it into a word problem.

Say that I have a factory that makes chocolate chip cookies, but they make a wide variety of cookies each with a different (integer) number of chips in them.

The chocolate chips themselves are stored in containers which hold a discrete, integer number of chips X. An order might ask for any number of cookies, and will contain multiple varities of cookies (e.g. An order might ask for 2 cookies with 5 chips, and 3 cookies with 4 chips). However, the machine that distributes the chips is only allowed to make one trip, and therefore must gather all the chips it needs from one container.

Therefore, is there a way to determine, knowing the contents of an order, the fewest number of containers possible such that if the cookies were made in *any possible order* the machine could always find enough chips in a single container to make the cookie?

A few assumptions can be made which simplify the problem:

- The cookie machine is relatively smart. It knows the chip count of all containers and can access any of them, and is not required to "finish" a container before using another.
- There will never be a case where a cookie requires more chips than 1 container provides
- This is a programming problem so recursive solutions are usable.

Right now I'm solving it by over-estimating the number of containers and chips I'm using, but that has a monetary cost to it. I'm sure the solution is simple, but for the life of me I can't make headway on it.

Comment: What are the constraints? How many types of cookies can there be, and what can the size of the orders be?

Comment: Anywhere from 2 to X where X is the number of chips the container can hold for the types of cookies. There will never be a one chip cookie. The size of the order can be 1 to infinity in theory. In practice its ~90-1000 cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the bin packing problem, which is NP hard. You can find a discussion of it in its [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem)